# Accessing a remote XML

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parser a xml file from this website (there actually are several ones following what you need) : https://developers.skplanetx.com/apidoc/eng/melon/chart/

Here is what I tried with the first one (without getting it working) :

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://apis.skplanetx.com/melon/charts/realtime?version=1&page=5&count=10');
foreach ($xml->melon->songs->song as $musique)
      echo "<tr><td>{$musique->currentRank}</td><td>{$musique->artist}</td><td>{$musique->songName}</td></tr>";
?>
```

Does anyone know how I could resolve this problem? I guess I can't access the original xml file...

Thank you !

Comment: http://apis.skplanetx.com/melon/charts/realtime?version=1&page=5&count=10 this url gives the json data in browser..

Comment: no.. not json data... a json error ;-)

Comment: The doc shows both XML and JSON..But I could not find how to specify the output format....The correct way to use the data is to get it first : `simplexml_load_file(file_get_contents('http://.....'));` or `json_decode(file_get_contents('...'));`

Comment: it seems that you are right for the XML one (I didn't try the JSON one).. the problem is that the informations I get aren't hierarchized, that's to say I cannot call them with the "foreeach" and "echo" above in my code script

Answer (score 1):

http://apis.skplanetx.com/melon/charts/realtime?version=1&page=5&count=10

In return you are getting error code 9405, check link below :

https://developers.skplanetx.com/develop/doc/error-code/

As per output, it says "precondition failed", but as per https://developers.skplanetx.com/apidoc/eng/melon/chart/#doc688 it says Pre-Conditions = N/A

I think you need to pass http://apis.skplanetx.com/melon/charts/realtime?version=1&page=5&count=10&appkey=XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

Check for your appkey and pass in above url

Answer (score 0):

It's JSON
so try

```
$data_raw = file_get_contents('http://apis.skplanetx.com/melon/charts/realtime?version=1&page=5&count=10');
$data_array = json_decode($data_raw);
print_r($data_raw);
```